# Html <p> tag as PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I was wondering if it's possible to get whatever is inside a `<p>` tag as a PHP variable so I can post it into the database. Here is the `<p>` tag I mean:

```
<p id="totaal"></p>
```

So my code in PHP is this:

```
$totaal = $_POST['totaal'];
```

Comment: you cah use a php HTML parser  as  DOMHtml  or others

Comment: why do you not use [input tags](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)?

Comment: Consider using input type `hidden` tag for this inside `form`tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submit a form, only the values of successful form controls will be included in the data sent to the server by the browser.

If you want to get the content of a paragraph, then you will need to either duplicate it in a form control or extract it using JavaScript/DOM and make the request using some means other than a form submission (such as via XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with your code. Can use **Php DOM parser**

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

other way is you can get the value of the **id** using java script variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var totaal = $('#totaal').text();
<?php $abc = "<script>document.write(totaal)</script>"?>   
</script>
<?php echo $abc;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the data from some page using php, do this

```
// get the html 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("index.html");
$div = $dom->getElementById('totaal');
print_r($div); //prints everything it gets
```

or maybe you want to just send the data from the same page to a php file to update it to the database, then :

```
content = $("#totaal").html();
$.ajax({
  url: "something/addToDatabase.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { something: content} 
  success: function(serverMessage){
    $("#output").html(serverMessage);
  }
});
```

and do the php stuff in `addToDatabase.php`